# luamplib Multiple beginfigures

Tags: luatex, metapost, luamplib

I'd like to include a METAPOST file that contains multiple `beginfig` blocks in my LuaLaTeX document. I'm including the file using `input filename ;` within a `mplibcode` environment, but this just places all the figures side by side. Is there a way to control the layout of the figures, e.g. to display them one above the other, or even to specify which figure from the file to include?

## Example

METAPOST file `stackx.mp`:

```
prologues := 3 ;
outputtemplate := "%j-%c.mps" ;

u := 1in ;

beginfig(0) ;

draw fullcircle scaled 2u ;

endfig ;

beginfig(1) ;

draw fullcircle scaled 2u ;
draw fullcircle scaled u shifted (u*right) ;

endfig ;

bye
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

{\hfill
\begin{mplibcode}
    input stackx.mp ;
\end{mplibcode}
\hfill}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

which produces:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that mplib provides any interface control to do this.  It's sort of designed to one figure in each `mplibcode` block. Can you explain *why* you need to do this?   The obvious approach would be to define each figure in line where you want them.

Comment: @Thruston Sometimes I'd like to be able to use the same graphics in multiple documents so inlining it every time seems less than optimal, plus I usually prefer not to mix document types within a file. I guess I could put each figure in a separate file, but then I'd need yet another file to put definitions shared between figures in, and it the code would be less cleanly divided into files according to function.

Comment: Right...  Each mplibcode block produces an hbox that you can save to a box register and reuse, but I don't think that's what you want here.  (It's explained [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/luatex/generic/luamplib/luamplib.pdf) and there's an example in the package test files).

Comment: May compile the shared MP pictures to PDFs and include them?  A good build tool can handle dependencies like that for you

Comment: @Thruston That's the workaround I'm using now. I was just hoping I might be able to avoid writing Makefiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`luamplib` just creates a hbox for every picture. You can save the list of hboxes in a new hbox and then access parts of this with some Lua code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{luamplib}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\showboxdepth\maxdimen
\showboxbreadth\maxdimen
\newbox\mympbox
\newcommand\evalmp[1]{\setbox\mympbox\hbox{\begin{mplibcode}input #1;\end{mplibcode}}}
\newcommand\usemp{\directlua{
  local b = tex.box.mympbox;
  if not b then
    error[[\noexpand\evalmp is required before \string\usemp]]
  end
  b = b.head
  for _ = 2,token.scan_int() do
    b = b and b.next
  end
  if b then
    node.write(node.copy(b))
  else
    error[[There are not enough saved figures]]
  end
}}
\newcommand\countmp{\directlua{tex.sprint(node.length(tex.box.mympbox.head))}}
\begin{document}
\evalmp{stackx.mp}
There are \countmp\ figures. The first two are

\hfil\usemp1\hfil

and

\hfil\usemp2\hfil

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course you could also use `expl3, forloop, ...` to iterate over the figures and create the layout you wish for.